# Why is (i+1) not the same as (i++)?

Tags: java

I'm absolutely new to coding. I'm doing a course and was following all steps but there is something I couldn't figure out.

This is the first code that I wrote. It prints 5 times `"Hello"`.

[image: For loop]

I tried to change the code. Instead of writing `i + 1`, I wrote `i++`, as the instructor told. It again should have printed 5 times `"Hello"`, but it runs infinitely.

[image: For loop]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No! don't use  `i = i++`, just use `i++`

Comment: It is because `i = i++`, increament happens after execution of `i = i` statement, which means value of `i` reamains same and does not change. Thus, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: did you read what `i++` does and returns?

Answer (score 3):

`i = i++` assigns the value of `i` before the increment i.e.
for `i = 0`  after `i = i++` it will still be equal to 0.
You never increment `i` and thereby never leave the loop.